# Is there an easy way to see how much I've made or lost with Sharebuilder over time?

Tags: investing

Is there an easy way to see how much I've made or lost with Sharebuilder over time?

OR do I have to manually go add all the fees, the monies put in and taken out and then compare it to what is in the account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Portfolio > Gains & Losses and click on "start Gain & Loss Tool". This will pop up a new window with detailed information. Not sure if it takes fees into account though...